# telnet file not found in etc/xinetd.d

Tags: lubuntu, telnet, xinetd

$apt-get install -y telnetd
$apt-get install -y xinetd

$ls /etc/xinetd.d

telnet is not found

Kindly help.

Comment: Hi Kingstan! Welcome to AskUbuntu!  Are you trying to install a telnet server or a telnet client?  Installing telnetd and xinetd suggests you are installing a telnet server, but calling telnet suggests you want a telnet client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`telnet` is the telnet client package.

`telnetd` is the telnet server package.

Try installing `telnet`

```
sudo apt install telnet
```

And, unless you want an open telnet port on your machine, uninstall `telnetd` also:

```
sudo apt remove telnetd
```